# Why are App Engine Datastore small operations DATASTORE_SMALL still billed according to appstats?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, appstats

In my appstats `_ah/stats`, one of the line says:

```
 @3717ms datastore_v3.Next real=21ms api=0ms cost=3000 billed_ops=[DATASTORE_SMALL:300]
```

I thought they are free, according to the [Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing) page.

This is the result of `EntityClass.query().filter(some filter).filter(some filter).fetch(keys_only=True)`.

Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not mistaken. It's a known issue that the pricing in Appstats is outdated. See [here](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11397&can=1&q=appstats%20commentby%3Arbruyere%40google.com&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log).